# Invalid allocation runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, operator-overloading

I have to replicate a vector class using an int and overload a bunch of operators. How ever every time I try to use the +, -, or / operator I get a runtime error which says invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes. Any feed back on how I can improve my code is welcome as well.

my code:
myArray.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class myArray{
private:
    int *A;
    int lenght;
    int maxSize;
public:
    myArray(){lenght = 0; maxSize = 0; A = new int[maxSize];}
    myArray(int s){maxSize = s; lenght = 0; A = new int[maxSize];}
    myArray(const myArray &M);
    ~myArray(){delete[] A;}
    const int getMaxSize(){return maxSize;}
    const int getLenght(){return lenght;}
    const myArray& operator +(const myArray& A); 
    const myArray& operator -(const myArray A);
    const int operator *(const myArray& A);
    const myArray& operator /(const myArray A);
    const myArray& operator +(int A); 
    const myArray& operator -(int A);
    const int operator *(int A);
    const myArray operator /(int A);
    const myArray operator ++();
    const myArray operator ++(int);
    const myArray operator --();
    const myArray operator --(int);
    myArray operator -();
    int operator [](int ind) const;
    myArray& operator =(const myArray& rho);
    void push(int n);
    int pop();
    void insert(int n, int pos);
    int remove(int pos);
    void resize(int newSize);
};
```

myException.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class myException: public exception
{
private:
    int code;
    string reason;
public:
    myException(){code = 0; reason = "Unknown";}
    myException(int c, string r){code = c; reason = r;}
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const myException A);
};  

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const myException A)
{
outputStream << "Code: " << A.code << "  Reason: " << A.reason << endl;
return outputStream;
}
```

myArray.cpp

```
#ifndef MYARRAY_H
#define MYARRAY_H
#include "myArray.h"
#include "myException.h"
//Copy contructor
myArray::myArray(const myArray &M)
{
    maxSize = M.maxSize;
    lenght = M.lenght;
    A = new int[maxSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < M.lenght; i++)
        A[i] = M.A[i];
}    
//Adds the elements of the array with each other and returns the result
const myArray& myArray::operator +(const myArray& secondArray)
{
    try
    {
        if(lenght != secondArray.lenght)
            throw myException(10, "Different sizes!");

        myArray result(secondArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
            result.A[i] = A[i] + secondArray.A[i];
        return result;
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
} 
//Subtracts the elements of the array with each other and returns the result
const myArray& myArray::operator -(const myArray secondArray)
{
    try
    {
        if(lenght != secondArray.lenght)
            throw myException(10, "Different sizes!");

        myArray result(secondArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
            result.A[i] = this->A[i] - secondArray.A[i];
        return result;
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}  
//Gets the dot product of 2 vectors
const int myArray::operator *(const myArray& secondArray)
{
    try
    {
        if(lenght != secondArray.lenght)
            throw myException(10, "Different sizes!");

        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
            result += this->A[i] * secondArray.A[i];
        return result;
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}  
//Divides the elements of the array with each other and returns the result 
const myArray& myArray::operator /(const myArray secondArray)
{ 
    try
    {
        if(lenght != secondArray.lenght)
            throw myException(10, "Different sizes!");

        myArray result(secondArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
            result.A[i] = this->A[i] / secondArray.A[i];
        return result;
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}    
//Adds the elements of the array with an int and returns the result
const myArray& myArray::operator +(int A)
{ 
    myArray result(*this);
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
        result = this->A[i] + A;
    return result;
} 
//Subtracts the elements of the array with an int and returns the result
const myArray& myArray::operator -(int A)
{
    myArray result(*this);
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
        result = this->A[i] - A;
    return result;
}
//Gets the dot product of a vector multiplied by an int
const int myArray::operator *(int A)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
        result += this->A[i] * A;
    return result;
} 
//Divides the elements of the array with an int and returns the result
const myArray myArray::operator /(int A)
{  
    myArray result(*this);
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght;i++)
        result = this->A[i] / A;
    return result;
}    

//increments every element in the array by 1(Pre-increment)
const myArray myArray::operator ++()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        ++A[i];

    return *this;
}
//increments every element in the array by 1(Post-increment)
const myArray myArray::operator ++(int)
{
    myArray temp(maxSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        temp.A[i] = A[i]++;

    return temp;
}
//decrements every element in the array by 1(Pre-decrement) 
const myArray myArray::operator --()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
         --A[i];

    return *this;
}
//decrements every element in the array by 1(Post-decrement)  
const myArray myArray::operator --(int)
{
    myArray temp(maxSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        temp.A[i] = A[i]--;

    return temp;
} 
//Makes every element in the array negative
myArray myArray::operator -()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        A[i] = -A[i];
    return *this;
}     
//returns the number in the array using []
int myArray::operator [](int ind) const
{
    try
    {
        if(ind > lenght)
            throw myException(60, "Array index out of bounds");

        return A[ind];
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
} 
//Assignment operator
myArray& myArray::operator=(const myArray& B)
{ 
    delete [] A;
    A = new int[B.maxSize];
    lenght = B.lenght;
    maxSize = B.maxSize;
    for(int i = 0; i < B.lenght; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B.A[i];
    }
    return (*this);
}

//pushes the value inserted to the next available spot in the array 
void myArray::push(int n)
{
    try
    {
        if(lenght == maxSize)
            throw myException(30, "Not enough space");

        if(lenght == 0)
        {
            A[0] = n;
            lenght++;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
            {
                if(i+1 == lenght)
                {
                    A[i+1] = n;
                    lenght++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}  
//Removes the last element in the array and returns it
int myArray::pop()
{
    try
    {
        if(lenght <= 0)
            throw myException(60, "Array index out of bounds");

        int temp = A[lenght - 1];
        A[lenght - 1] = NULL;
        lenght--;
        return temp;
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}  
inserts an element at the specified position
void myArray::insert(int n, int pos)
{
    try
    {
        if(pos > lenght)
            throw myException(60, "Array index out of bounds");

        for(int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++)
        {
            if(i == pos)
            {
                A[i-1] = n;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}  
//removes an element at a specified position an returns the value.
int myArray::remove(int pos)
{
    try
    {
        if(pos < 0 || (pos > lenght -1))
            throw myException(50, "Invalid Position");

        int temp = A[pos];
        A[pos] = NULL;

        for(int i = pos; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            A[i] = A[i+1];
        }

        return temp;

    }
    catch(myException& e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }

}    
//Re sizes the entire array
void myArray::resize(int newSize)
{
    int *B;
    B = new int[newSize];
    maxSize = newSize;
    for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        B[i] = A[i];

    delete[] A;
    A = B;
}

#endif
```

This is just a dummy main to test everything on the myArray class

main.cpp

```
#include "myArray.h"

int main()
{
    int num;
    myArray vector1;
    myArray vector2(5);
    myArray vector3;
    vector1.resize(5);
    //cout << "Max Size: " << vector1.getMaxSize() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        vector1.push(num);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        vector2.push(num);
    }

    vector3 = vector1 + vector2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << vector3.pop() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Interesting. You have a member variable called `A` and you name your function arguments `A`. Interview failed.

Comment: You're not going to like this advice, but I'm going to be painfully honest with you. You should start over. You've written a lot of code and you clearly understand very little of it. Start again and don't just write the code, run it through the debugger and watch what it does. Take the time to make your code readable and meaningful. And come back with individual questions about individual items you're not sure about. Also, when you overwrite a pointer `A = new [maxSize]` the previous value doesn't get de-allocated automatically. This is called a memory leak. You has it. Also: 'length'.

Answer (score 0):

You create dynamic array with zero size in default constructor.
But in `push` method you try to set value to it if it's length is zero.

In C++ standard it says:

> The effect of dereferencing a pointer returned as a request for zero
>   size is undefined.

You can only delete it. Fix your `push` method